# Emulating SPARC hardware

Tags: solaris, emulation, emulator

I need a software who emulate SPARC system (Hardware) in a Windows 7 host computer.
I need to install a Solaris SPARC 10 for developing purpose and I don't have a SPARC machine.

Can you give me some advice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're likely to have only one option as far as sparc emulation on windows 7 goes - QEMU - which is the only common emulator supporting dissimilar architectures.

If it works, it'll likely to be MUCH slower than a real system , and [apparently it dosen't work yet](https://opensolaris.org/jive/thread.jspa?threadID=137821&tstart=-1)

Comment: well, i suspect other than architecture, solaris x86 software should work on solaris SPARC with a recompile. Might be worth testing

Comment: I have a SPARC software to install in a SPARC Solaris 10. I don't think that I can recompile it, I have only the executable file.

Comment: then, no, there's really not much you can do.

Comment: SPARC hardware isn't the cheapest in the world, but occasionally you can find some deals out there on used equipment.  I've had a few SPARC machines in my life that I got screaming bargains on.  Buying actual hardware might be your solution.

Answer (score 0):

If Solaris 8 is acceptable, you might want to evaluate sybil: http://www.stromasys.ch/hardware-virtualization-solutions/virtual-sparcstation/

Otherwise, I would also recommend buying used hardware.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But how can I get it? Freeware software does not include the Spark emulator.

Comment: It is indeed a commercial solution. I don't know this software price but used hardware might be cheaper.